# Unit testing an IExtension<OperationContext> for use with WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, unit-testing

I'm trying to develop a extension (`IExtension<OperationContext>`) for System.ServiceModel.ObjectContext using TDD. The extension is to be used as storage for a lifetime manager to be used with Windsor Castle.

The problem lies in abstracting (mocking) the OperationContext. As it is a static object that gets automatically created during runtime I don't really know how to mock it (without TypeMock - which I don't have).

An OperationContext can be newed up if I supply a channel object that implements IChannelFactory, however - that interface is scary complex, and I don't know what stuff I have to implement in a stub to get it working properly.

Hosting the service and calling it doesn't populate the OperationContext either...

```
[TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void FixtureSetup()
    {
        _serviceHost = new TypeResolverServiceHost(typeof(AilDataService));
        _serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof (IAilDataService), new BasicHttpBinding(), SvcUrl);
        _serviceHost.Open();

        var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(SvcUrl);

        _ailDataService = ChannelFactory<IAilDataService>.CreateChannel(new BasicHttpBinding(), endpointAddress);
    }

    [TestFixtureTearDown]
    public void FixtureCleanup()
    {
        _serviceHost.Close();
    }

    [Test]
    public void Can_Call_Service()
    {
        var reply = _ailDataService.GetMovexProductData("169010", new TaskSettings{MovexDatabase = "MVXCDTATST", MovexServer = "SEJULA03"});

        Assert.That(reply, Is.Not.Null);

        // This fails
        Assert.That(OperationContext.Current!=null);
    }
```

Any tips?

Comment: Have you looked at the Castle Windsor WCF Facility instead of doing a lot of this work yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
    [TestFixture]
public class WcfPerSessionLifestyleManagerTests
{
    private const string SvcUrl = "http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/JulaAil.DataService.WcfService/AilDataService/";

    private TypeResolverServiceHost _serviceHost;
    private ChannelFactory<IAilDataService> _factory;
    private IAilDataService _channel;
    private WindsorContainer _container;

    [Test]
    public void Can_Populate_OperationContext_Using_OperationContextScope()
    {
        using (new OperationContextScope((IContextChannel) _channel))
        {
            Assert.That(OperationContext.Current, Is.Not.Null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code does not make sense, what is TypeResolverServiceHost? Could you post the full setup, test, teardown please?